# entity framework load only parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to load an entity from **Entity Framework(EF)** but I only need the entity itself, I don't need any childs. I'm having troubles sending an object trought sockets because of the weight of the object.**(Any suggestion about this?)**

**I'm using this code to get the list of objects I need:**

```
…
private static DBEntities context = new DBEntities();
listaPlatos = context.PLATO.ToList();
…
```

My problem is that each object "PLATO" has others objects as childs. I want to ignore that childs and get only the "PLATO" entity.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using code fist? if you are you can create a custom class that references the PLATO entity, but ignores any mappings.

Comment: by default, entity framework does not include child objects, unless you use `.Include()`

Comment: Every object PLATO in listaPlatos List has another object related to the entity in the database. I need to load only the PLATO object, without related objects

Comment: can you show your PLATO class declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't use an explicit loading of children, I guess lazy loading may cause you problems.
Check out
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Here is a relevant link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: That solved my problem Mattias, thanks for the quick answer. Any suggestion about saving some bytes sendings objects throught sockets? I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for Serialize-DeSerialize but it cost me about 4MB to transmit 4 database records.

Comment: Ouch! Json is noy very expensive in itself. Id take a serious look at what properties are really needed, wrap those in a poco class and export that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the serializer. A solution could be to use another class which is a pure POCO DTO class (this is always a best practise when you serializing something over the wire (sockets, WCF, whatever)).

```
var listaPlatos = context.PLATO.Select(x => new PlatoDto {
    Prop1 = x.SomeProp
});
```